# Are there any built-in Express middleware to validate empty path segments?

Tags: node.js, express

I have multiple endpoints defined on my express app.

One endpoint is similar as follows:

```
app.route('/v2/api/pdf/:month?')
  .get((req, res, next) => {
    // implementation  
});

app.param('month', (req, res, next, month) => {
    // when month is empty, it never comes here.
});
```

I know I can validate if `month` is empty on the endpoint callback, but what if I have multiple endpoints with different segments and want to handle the case when it's empty on a single place, how can I do that without using the `app.use` middleware?

Comment: Uhhh, `app.use()` is how you do things in one place.  So, why are you looking for a solution that doesn't use `app.use()`?

Comment: I just wanted, in this case, to evaluate its emptyness. So I thought it would make it cleaner if I did app.param(['x', 'y', 'z'], ...) instead of a bunch of ifs inside app.use.